# Use function return value outside defined function

Tags: python-2.7

In the example below, the output of

> print files

comes out as `None`. Why is that?

```
topdir = 'some_directory'
exten = '.txt'

def step(ext, dirname, names):
    ext = ext.lower()

    for name in names:
        if name.lower().endswith(ext):
            return os.path.join(dirname, name)

files = os.path.walk(topdir, step, exten)
print files
```

Please note that the program finds the correct files. I tested this by using `print` instead of `return`. It is just that I am unable to retrieve information outside of the function. I would like files to be an array so I can use it later in the program. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `step()` function takes three arguments (`ext`, `dirname`, and `names`), but when you are using it in `os.path.walk` you aren't giving it any - it is being passed as an argument instead of a function. Try passing it the required number of arguments and seeing if your code works then.

Comment: Well, to be more precise, OP is *passing* the function `step` as an argument, rather than calling the function and passing its return value.

Comment: @senshin correct, I updated my answer slightly to reflect that distinction.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I do not know what arguments to give for step(). I am new to Python and found the above example on the internet. Could you please guide me?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to get the full path of the files in an array so I can use these files later in the program. In other words, I would like print files to print: [filepath/file1.txt, filepath/file2.txt,...].

Comment: The program gives me the filepaths correctly. Just that I cannot get it out of the defined function. As it stands the print files statement prints None. I would like it to print an array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after much searching online, I think I have a solution. The import statements are inside the function because I would like to be self-consistent so that I can invoke it from outside. But that's a second step.

It would be great if this can be improved. But I think it does exactly what I want:

```
def file_search(dir, pattern):
    import os
    import fnmatch 

    images = [pattern]
    matches = []

    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir):
        for extensions in images:
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, extensions):
                matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return matches

files = file_search('/Users/aging_gorrila/RESEARCH/python_files/', '*.py')
print files[0]
```

I get the following output:

```
['/Users/aging_gorrila/RESEARCH/python_files/file_search.py']
```

Comment: or you can simply use glob.glob(path+pattern)